# How can I configure sonar-scanner to not warn on files not matching forced language?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We're using SonarQube 6.3 with a PHP project.  We have the sonar.language property set to php since that's what we're interested in.  We have exclusions configured so some vendor libraries are not included in the scan.  These exclusions work for the actual analysis but our scan log is full of warnings about files being ignored because they aren't php.

Sample warning:

```
WARN: File 'vendor/somejavascriptlib/cooljavascript.js' is ignored because it doens't belong to the forced langauge 'php'
```

We have sonar.exclusions set to "vendor/**/*" but that doesn't seem to impact the file indexing that is creating these warnings. Is there a way to supress the warning?  Or a different config property we should be using?

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be fixed in SonarQube 6.6: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9561

Comment: Look forward to the release.

Comment: We get this message even with SonarQube 7.6.

Comment: Note that `sonar.language` is deprecated for a long time, and finally removed in 7.7. So I won't spend time to investigate your case, sorry.